# Alert for an OS X application

Tags: cocoa, macos

I have to bring up an alert when a certain event in my app has been fired.

What is the best way to do it? I can not use Growl because my app will be submitted on the Mac App Store and it does not mean that user will use Growl.

But I'd like something similar.

At best, an alert like calendar events from iCal. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You mean like an NSAlert?

```
NSAlert *alert = [[[NSAlert alloc] init] autorelease];
[alert addButtonWithTitle:@"OK"];
[alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];
[alert setMessageText:@"Delete the record?"];
[alert setInformativeText:@"Deleted records cannot be restored."];
[alert setAlertStyle:NSWarningAlertStyle];
[alert beginSheetModalForWindow:[self window] modalDelegate:self didEndSelector:@selector(alertDidEnd:returnCode:contextInfo:) contextInfo:nil];
```

Comment: I mean something like the iCal notifications, in the past I was using Growl to notify events like Skype does but now I want a solution that does not use any external components. My events are notifications on something that has happened like "It's time to go home".

Comment: You can use push notifications. They're new in Lion.

Comment: Unfortunately local push notifications are only available on iOS.